# DICOM viewer - highlight a specific area

Tags: javascript, dicom, papaya

I am using papaya to view a DICOM image. I want to highlight a specific region of the image when a user drags over a region.

I was trying to use Jcrop plugin, but it does not seem to work. Is there a fix in doing that? Or does the papaya viewer have a built in function to capture the drag event?

Comment: Do you have some existing code that you can show? Otherwise it will be difficult to answer the first part of your question, where you're asking about a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing JCrop is designed to work with `<img>` not `<canvas>`, but maybe this will be helpful: [Cropping image drawn into canvas with JCrop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647086/cropping-image-drawn-into-canvas-with-jcrop)

In Papaya, take a look at these in [viewer.js](https://github.com/rii-mango/Papaya/blob/master/src/js/viewer/viewer.js):

```
papaya.viewer.Viewer.prototype.mouseDownEvent
papaya.viewer.Viewer.prototype.mouseMoveEvent (see isDragging)
papaya.viewer.Viewer.prototype.mouseUpEvent

// these might be useful to set a command-key to enable your feature
papaya.viewer.Viewer.prototype.keyDownEvent
papaya.viewer.Viewer.prototype.keyUpEvent
```

Note, there are already several features that listen to mouse moving and dragging, so you'd have to work around those (maybe add a new command-key for your action) or disable the existing behavior.